# Sqlite inserting issue in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, insert

I need to store user doubleTap count in db. Its working fine.
If i am doing very fast double tapping to insert, issues will appear (database is locked, no such table: and out of memory). How to handle that issue?

Thanks in Advance

I tried this, FYI:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void)
{

@try {
        if([self openAppDatabase] == YES) //If DB open success...
        {
            sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
            NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@,%@) values (?,?)",Tables_Count,lkt_TO,ttt_TIME];
            BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseObj, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
            if(prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [contactNo  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [sentDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                    DLog(@"Can't insert ---- Error");
                }
            }
            else {
                // In the database cannot be opened then show the error message on the debugger.
                DLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseObj));
            }
            // Release the compiled statement from memory.
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        [self closeAppDatabase]; //If DB not opened will close it here...
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DLog(@"@Exception --- %@",exception.reason);
    }


 }
```

Comment: You are updating db too frequently, that's why it is causing issues.
You can keep a local variable that stores count of doubleTap.
And update the db when user leaves that screen.

Comment: Instead of running your data insert on an arbitrary background queue, create a single background queue and use that one queue for all database updates. This will serialize all of your updates. Also, why open and close the database every time? Open the database once when you app starts and use the same connection throughout.

Comment: Also, why close the database if it doesn't open? Why finalize the prepared statement even it is fails to prepare?

Comment: @Aneeq - double tap is just like sending different images

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch queue you are using is a concurrent queue, not a series queue. The result is that too many requests are being made to the dB at a time. You should be ok if you change your code to use `dispatch_barrier_async` but I've never used it on system queues.

Additionally, you're code could use some cleanup. The `try` is unnecessary since this code does not throw exceptions. Contrary to Java, Objective Chicago very rarely throws exceptions.

Lastly, you may consider using a Objective C SQLite wrapper, like FMDatabase. It cleans things up quite a bit.